# How do I add columns to expand a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Sorry I couldn't think of a more informative title, but here's my challenge. I have a matrix and I need to add columns in specific places based on parameters described by a vector. For example, if I have the following matrix:

```
1, 0, 1, 2, 0
0, 0, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 0, 0, 0
2, 0, 1, 0, 2
```

but for a particular R package (unmarked), I need to add columns of NA in specific place. I have a vector relating the columns in the matrix:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 3
```

Which indicates that columns 1-3 were from the same sampling period and columns 4 and 5 were from different sampling periods. I need to make the number of columns in the matrix equal the max number from the same sampling period times the number of sampling periods. In this case there are three 1s (max number of any unique value in the vector) and a total of three sampling periods (max number in the vector). So I need a matrix with 9 columns (3 x 3). Specifically, I need to add the new columns of NAs after the 4th and 5th columns. Basically, I just need columns of NAs to be placeholders to have a matrix where the number of observations (each column) is the same (=3) for each of the sample periods (indicated by the number in the vector). This is difficult to describe but in this imaginary example I would want to end up with:

```
1, 0, 1, 2, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA
0, 0, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA
1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA
2, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA
```

this would be described by a vector that looked like:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3
```

although I don't actually need to produce that vector, just the matrix. Obviously, it was easy to add those columns in this case, but for my data I have a much bigger matrix that will end up with ~200 columns. Plus I will likely have to do this for numerous data sets.

Can anyone help me with a way to code this in R so that I can automate the process of expanding the matrix?

Thanks for any advice or suggestions!

---

EDIT:
to make things a bit more similar to my actual data here is a reproducible matrix and vector similar to my current ones:

```
    m <- matrix(rpois(120*26, 1), nrow = 120, ncol = 26)
    v <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7)
```

Comment: OK, so you say you don't have to produce the vector, and therefore it doesn't already exist... what information do you already have that indicates which sampling period has the most columns?  Or, do you know it's the first 3 and that it's simply a matter of inserting two new ones after each additional column of your 200?

Comment: Sorry, I would always know from my sampling and creating of the matrix which sampling period has the most columns and how many that was. Those columns would always be adjacent but could occur anywhere in the matrix. Because of the ease, I would always probably create the first vector, I just meant that I don't need to create the second vector corresponding to the final relationship since it would always be just multiples of the max observations (columns) per primary period.

Comment: Simply `cbind(mat[,1:3],nas,nas,mat[,4:5]` (using definition of `nas` from Johns answer) will do for small sets. Are your sampling periods always grouped, that is never do you see `1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,3` ?  I'm thinking up simple functions to generate the locations of the new NA columns, which is why I ask.  I would also like to ask just what package or function you're sending the final matrix into?  There is often a better way to assemble your data if we know what you need to accomplish.  Stuffing in all those NAs is probably not the best solution :-)

Comment: Thanks, unforunately the NAs are currently necessary for the current version of the R package "unmarked" for open populations (function: unmarkedFramePCO) because it tries to divide the matrix into equal sets of columns based on the value in the argument numPrimary. Therefore, it will later remove the NAs. The sampling periods will therefore always be grouped but need an equal number of observations (columns) per sample period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `m` is the matrix and `v` is the vector, you can use something like

```
 t = table(v)
 size = dim(m)[1] * max(t)   # size of each block based on the longest
 matrix(unlist(lapply(names(t), function(i) {
               x = m[, v == i]                  # get the short block
               c(x, rep(NA, size - length(x)))  # extend it to size
         })), dim(m)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the matrix just as you asked assuming the matrix is mat:

```
nr <- nrow(mat)
nas <- rep(NA, nr)
l <- lapply( 4:ncol(mat), function(x) matrix(c(mat[,x],nas,nas), nrow = nr) )
cbind(mat[,1:3], do.call(cbind,l))
```